# select descendants where attribute is x and if doesnt exist select where attribute is y

Tags: c#, linq

I have this and i can select what i want when period is 2. But if period 2 do not exist i want to select where period is 3 instead. How?

```
 return document.Descendants("time")
                        .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("period") == "2")
                        .Take(5)
                        .Select(status => WeatherFactory.Create(status, city, pos))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first select all descendants where period == 2, check if it contains any results, and if it doesn't select all descendants where period == 3:

```
var timeDescendants = document.Descendants("time")
   .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("period") == "2");
if(!timeDescendants.Any()) {
   timeDescendants = document.Descendants("time")
      .Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("period") == "3");
}
return timeDescendants.Take(5)
.Select(status => WeatherFactory.Create(status, city, pos))
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just change the Where to:

```
.Where(node => (string)node.Attribute("period") == "2" || (string)node.Attribute("period") == "3")
```

?

Comment: But actually. Now it selects both.. :(